# Get the last uri segment of the first a in the the td:last-child of a table row

Tags: jquery

I have this html containing a table with share prices

```
<tr id='row-7'>
<td>Glencore</td>
<td>Share Price</td>
<td>360</td>
<td class='actions'>
<a href="http://localhost/ye/index.php/enterprise/addressbook/read/21345" class="edit_button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-primary" role="button">
<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-document"></span>
<span class="ui-button-text">&nbsp;View</span>
</a>
<a href="http://localhost/ye/index.php/enterprise/addressbook/delete/21345" class="delete_button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-primary" role="button">
<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-document"></span>
<span class="ui-button-text">&nbsp;Delete</span>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

I have many rows in the table and i want to grab all the last segments of `a` of all rows with the class name `.selected`.

This the `a` `<a href="http://localhost/ye/index.php/enterprise/addressbook/read/21345" class="edit_button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-primary" role="button">
<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-document"></span>
<span class="ui-button-text">&nbsp;View</span>
</a>`

The last uri segment i want to read is `21345` but i want to read for all rows and also grab the last uri and have them in a comma delimited list.

This is the jquery i have so far

```
var last_uri_segments = $('.mytable tr.selected td:last-child').map(function () {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    var last_segment = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    return this.last_segment;
    }).get().join(',');

    alert(last_uri_segments);
```

My first question is how i would target the last `a` coming first in the last child of td.

Update

This is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4tpwq94b/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
var $selectedRows = $("table tr.selected");
var idsFound = [];
$selectedRows.each(function() {
    var url = $(this).find("td").last().find("a").first().attr("href");
    var lastSegment = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, url.length);
    idsFound.push(lastSegment);
});
console.log(idsFound.join(","));
```

Comment: Cheers.
The other one looks better but doesn't quite work according to your specs. It returns the last segment of *any* A tag that is in the row. No matter the position in the row/cell.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var uriList = $('tr.selected a').map(function(){
   return this.href.split('/').reverse()[0];              
}).get();
```

Now you can just use `uriList.join(',')` to make it a comma separated values.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4tpwq94b/3/)

Comment: This shows blank when i try running it.Its not the `a` that has the class `selected`.

Comment: can you prepare a jsfiddle?

Comment: @user3286430 ah! I didn't see that. Now fixed

Comment: @Thanks @Amit. I am still having a minor problem.It displays the list but in this format `161,161,javascript:void(0),40,40,javascript:void(0)`

Comment: @user3286430 the problem was you didn't include `<table>` tag. So it was invalid markup. Now it works

Comment: Looks good! It's just not limitting the a search to the first element.